# Installing local plugin via jenkins-cli

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

1. I've enabled 'Enable CLI over remoting'.
2. I've set TCP port for JNLP either fixed or random.
3. I've downloaded the jenkins-cli.jar successfully.

when preforming plugin-install command i receive:

- When executing: java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -auth user:pass -s http://localhost:8080 install-plugin file:///folder/plugin.hpi

  ERROR: Unexpected exception occurred while performing install-plugin command.
  java.io.FileNotFoundException: /folder/plugin.hpi (No such file or directory)
- Without the file://

  /folder/plugin.hpi is neither a valid file, URL, nor a plugin artifact name in the update center

I've tried every possible combination, the file does exist.

Edit: from the exception it keeps thinking that it's url instead of file:

```
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    at hudson.FilePath.copyFrom(FilePath.java:890)
```

"

Edit 2: It does work when given HTTP URL, but it will require me to upload it to a server which I don't have every time.

Edit 3: I tried moving the file to the same folder of Jenkins /var/lib/jenkins and give it permissions of 777.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL that you provide as argument to `install-plugin` must be accessible by the Jenkins master process. If you get the error message

```
/folder/plugin.hpi (No such file or directory)
```

then there's most likely a problem with access rights, or `/folder` is not mounted on the master's host (or in the master's container, if you use docker).

This is why a HTTP URL does work.

So, for `file://` URLs, you need to align filesystem mounts and permissions between CLI user/machine and Jenkins master user/machine.

Comment: I am logged in as a root and the plugin is located on master's host, and I don't use docker. Not sure what can I do.

Comment: I double-checked that plugin installation via CLI does work with a `file://` URL, so this must be some access problem. In the master's script console, could you try running the command `new File("/folder/plugin.hpi").exists()`? Output should be `true`. If not, then please try for all path components, one-by-one, to find the culprit.

Comment: I think you were correct! now I am getting Connection refused instead of the file not found, any clues on that?

Comment: Where did you get that `connection refused` error - in script console?

Comment: After running the install-plugin it says ERROR: Unexpected exception occurred while performing install-plugin command.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Comment: This must be a different problem I think,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182321/discussion-between-dannz-and-alex-o).

Answer (score 2):

It was a combination of @Alex O solution, and that I used -auth myuser:mypass instead of --username admin --password password and toggled --remoting.

It looks like this:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://host-ip:8080/ -remoting install-plugin ./plugin.hpi --username my-user --password my-pass -restart
```